# "the ride never ends"

Tags: idioms

Having a hard time understanding an idiom a person used on an anonymous bbs.

> Remember, the ride never ends.

What could he have meant by this? I'm aware that it's a reference to an old video game meme or something, but it's still very confusing.

[image]

Comment: There aren't too many hits for "ride never ends" on Google, and they seem all to be games-related: I'd say it's not a mainstream expression [yet].

Comment: This seems to explain the sign but it's nothing to do with English Language and Usage, it just seems to mean a ride that's very long or never ends https://creepypasta.fandom.com/wiki/Mr._Bones%27_Wild_Ride

Comment: Generally, a ride at a theme park has a beginning and end. It is a thrill. If, on the other hand, it never ends, it is a horror. Imagine being on a roller coaster forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The ride never ends" is an expression used to refer to life,  a life of specific kind (e.g., a life of crime), a career, a chronic medical condition, an emotional state, a book, etc. compared explicitly to a roller coaster ride (both having ups and downs) or seen as some kind of *endless ride*, e.g., a carousel, going round and round.

The expression can refer to the good/bad, positive/negative experiences or feelings a person actually undergoes or the range of emotions one experiences in a TV series or book (all ostensibly "desirable", even if harrowing or sad). Judging from Google Books, it appears the expression began in the 1990's. See the last example for bulletin-board usage.

> I have seen firsthand the link between anxiety and depression. The
> possibility for the chronically anxious person to become depressed is
> real and the reasons an be compelling. Earlier I likened the anxious
> state to being constantly on red alert. The mind and the body are in a
> heightened condition all the time. However, unlike the temporary
> thrill of a roller coaster, **this ride never ends.** [G. Jantz and A.
> McMurray; *Overcoming Anxiety, Worry, and Fear*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Life_the_Gift_That_Keeps_on_Giving/-cc-DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=two%20repeaters%20in%20my%20class&pg=PT34&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

> Emotionally, life as an alcoholic is a roller-coaster ride. The only
> problem is **the ride never ends**. [Joy Wingersky et al.; *Writing
> Paragraphs and Essays*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Writing_Paragraphs_and_Essays/sAl6P5r7XEIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22the%20ride%20never%20ends%22&dq=%22the%20ride%20never%20ends%22&printsec=frontcover) (1994)

> Grieving really is like a giant hill on a roller coaster ride. I am
> either going up or down, and **the ride *never* ends**...at least
> right now. [Carol Hetherington; *Beyond the Valley*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Beyond_the_Valley/9-ka6E5jiG4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the%20ride%20never%20ends%22&pg=PA46&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

> But it also takes us into the heart of the writer: and that journey,
> with its beauty and compassion , its conscience and courage , is so
> thrilling that we hope **the ride never ends**.  [G. Roberts, blurb
> for Carl Hoffman; *The Lunatic Express*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Lunatic_Express/lVeANZvyproC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the%20ride%20never%20ends%22&pg=PP4&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

> I hope you are as excited as I am to gon this journey. It's going to be a hell of a ride. Something to keep in mind, **this ride never ends**. It's a way of
> eating, a way of fueling your body that can last a lifetime. [Autumn
> Calabrese; *Lose Weight Like Crazy Even If You Have a Crazy Life!*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Lose_Weight_Like_Crazy_Even_If_You_Have/KH3oDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22ride%20never%20ends%22&pg=PT14&printsec=frontcover)
> (2020)

> "One moment, *My Soul to Keep* will have you laughing out loud, and
> the next you'll be under the covers with a flashlight, questioning
> unseen things, and hoping **the ride never ends**..." [Creston Mapes,
> blurb in Melanie Wells; *My Soul to Keep*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/My_Soul_to_Keep/u8OQjZWh8qAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22ride%20never%20ends%22&pg=PP5&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

> To someone who aspires to be a Principal Or Expert Artist, remember to
> keep the drive of always working to be better and love the challenge
> of that. **The ride never ends** until it ends. [Chris Wells in Paul Jones; *Game
> Artist: The Ultimate Career Guide*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Game_Artist/zBtQEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the%20ride%20never%20ends%22&pg=PT167&printsec=frontcover) (2021)

> They get on the caregiving carousel and find **the ride never ends**.
> I call them career caregivers. [Sherri Snelling; *A Cast of
> Caregivers*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Cast_of_Caregivers/ImqHg6-KSS8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the%20ride%20never%20ends%22&pg=PA179&printsec=frontcover) (2013)

> It has been like a wild roller coaster ride, up and down with twists
> and turns, but **the ride never ends**. Not until death. [Michael
> Gambino; *The Honored Society*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Honored_Society/4ZUrHzJl7o8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22the%20ride%20never%20ends%22&dq=%22the%20ride%20never%20ends%22&printsec=frontcover) (2001)

> You can say they "Keep Calm and Flutter On"! Or, as some on
> 4chan's/mlp/ board would put it, “**the ride never ends**.” And who
> can blame them for sticking around: In Dr. Plante's opinion, the
> show's eighth season was among its best!  [Patrick Edwards et al.;
> *Meet the Bronies*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Meet_the_Bronies/Q76tDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the%20ride%20never%20ends%22&pg=PA260&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a misremembered / simplified version of...

> ***[The road goes on forever](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/2gkxa9/the_road_goes_on_forever_but_the_party_never_ends/)** [but the party never ends]*

...which has been used as a (primarily, US "country music") album and song title (more than one of each, I think). My above link is to a Reddit discussion about the "meaning", where I'd say this guy has nailed it...

> *...meaning life will be irritating because it's **always the same routine** every day, but **the party never ending** means that you will never stop having fun.*

Comment: This is certainly a possible suggestion. Roads and rides tie together in riding motorbikes, which can be seen as an [existential metaphor for life](https://the-artifice.com/easy-rider-an-artful-american-souvenir/) (e.g. the film Easy Rider). There's also the sense of the theme park ride as a metaphor for life, because you're strapped in and have to endure the highs and lows (["life is a rollercoaster"](https://medium.com/the-mission/why-roller-coasters-are-great-metaphors-for-life-5515b43a7f57) is a well-known metaphor). It's all guesswork though from the original question.